# How can you fix the blurryness of pictures in Blender Render?

Tags: rendering

[image: When i use render pictures like these come up really blurry.]

I really need help with this, and the image when rendered is really blurry.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, and we can't really help without more info. Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/95508/edit) your question and clarify what the issue is, and post some relevant info like render settings, materials node setup, screenshots of the issue, etc.

Comment: Part of the issue could be that you are zooming past the resoulution of the image. 720x1280 is a small frame, and if you zoom in so far you will see all kinds of artifacts, starting with pixelation...

Answer (score 1):

That kind of noise is usually caused by things such as ambient occlusion or indirect lighting. Go to your world settings and at the bottom and in the Gather panel (assuming you have Raytrace enabled) increase the samples. This will increase render times but should smooth things out.